# Command line: retrieving specific column from CSV file

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal

I have a CSV file called `articles.csv` with headers as follows:
`article_id, article_title, article_shares, article_date`.

The first row of data in the article is found as `$ articles.csv | sed "1 d"` and this returns: `"895", "Trump, Clinton, America. Who will win, who will lose?", "100", "01/05/2016"`.

I want to return the fourth column of data (the date of the article) so I use the following code:
`$ articles.csv | sed "1 d" | cut -d , -f 4`.

However I don't get the date, I get `America. Who will win`. How do I get the output of the fourth column, regardless of the fact that some columns have commas in them?

Comment: When the data is recalcitrant like that, you need something that recognizes the CSV format properly.  Such code isn't all that hard to write in C, or Perl, or Python.  It is rather complex to write in just shell.  If you must do it with standard shell utilities, Awk is probably your best friend — assuming neither Perl nor Python is regarded as standard.  Perl has CSV modules, but you might need to get them installed.  I think Python has it CSV module installed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution:

```
... | awk -F'",' '{print $4}'
```

A slow but clean solution:

```
... | ruby -ne $'require "csv"; print CSV.parse($_)[0][3]'
```

Note: CSV format should not have spaces between fields, so change your record to:

```
"895","Trump, Clinton, America. Who will win, who will lose?","100","01/05/2016"
```